# How to record hours played on Steam offline?

Tags: steam

My wife often plays online games on my Steam account and I play lots of offline games so I usually log into Steam in Offline Mode but I would like these hours to be recorded so I got a log of how long I've played a game.
As I've found out, if I'm connected to internet when I quit a game, Steam does record the time played but if I've been offline when I quit the game, Steam doesn't seem to clock those hours.
I've been told there is a workaround to this. Does anybody know?
Thanks.

Comment: If Steam doesn't support what you want, you might want to use one of the apps that track how much time you spend in every app on your devices, take a look at the list here: https://alternativeto.net/software/clockify/

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to the Internet, did you restart Steam to check the counter? If the meter doesn't add hours spent in the game in this way, then you can set the status Offline for friends, but have an internet connection, then Steam will count your hours spent in the game.

Comment: Yes I did connect to the internet afterwards but the hours played were not recorded. Regarding your second solution, having an internet connection would indeed solve the problem but my wife will be kicked out of the game she's playing. So it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: There is one more way - create a new account and share games from the main account using Steam Family Sharing. Hours will count on the second account, not the main account.